# Proper storage of micrometer-adjustable torque wrenches

Tags: tools

[Sturtevant's website](https://www.srtorque.com/error-proofing-tools/micrometer-adjustable-torque-wrenches/) has the following warning:

> Relieving the tension down to the lowest setting
> on some micrometer adjustable torque wrenches
> can cause the tool to go out of tolerance
> and you won't know it.

I've always seen that practice recommended. What is that would cause some wrenches to go out of tolerance when they are stored with the tension at its lowest setting?

Comment: Loading an unloading a spring will eventually wear it out, depending on the material and amount of flexture. Less adjustment = less motion. It seems similar to magazine springs, which people have argued about for ages (leave the mags loaded or unload them). Science tells us that leaving a metal spring compressed doesn't wear it out over time, using it does. However it going against common sense so people still argue about it.

Comment: Thanks.  If the tool is used infrequently, say once every few months, it wouldn't matter much either way? Being left in the relaxed state is not, in and of itself, an issue; it is the *repetitive* compression and relaxation that causes the tool to fall out of tolerance?

Comment: Yes I believe that is the case.